# Builing forms in js instead of HTML

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm thinking about builing forms in js not in html.
I found one solution alpaca.js - http://www.alpacajs.org/
Are there other solutions? Which is best? Do You recommend builing forms with js?

Comment: Questions seeking library recommendations are off-topic.

Comment: "Do You recommend builing forms with js?" — Questions seeking opinions are off-topic

Answer (score -1):

We can dynamically add form elements in javascript.
Shown below is a simple one for your reference:
Try with this adding in your body of HTML

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        var f = document.createElement("form");
        f.setAttribute('method',"post");
        f.setAttribute('action',"submit.php");

        var i = document.createElement("input"); 
        i.setAttribute('type',"text");
        i.setAttribute('name',"username");

        var j = document.createElement("input"); 
        j.setAttribute('type',"password");
        j.setAttribute('name',"username");

        var s = document.createElement("input"); 

        s.setAttribute('type',"submit");
        s.setAttribute('value',"Submit");

        f.appendChild(i);
        f.appendChild(j);
        f.appendChild(s);

        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(f);
   </script>
```